# Find Difference Equation From Frequency Response

Tags: frequency-response

Given the frequency response $H (jω) = csc(ω)$ how would I go about finding the difference equation?  I know I can find $h[n]$ from here but after that I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: okay, so what **is** $h[n]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so, if we're looking around for a discrete-time difference equation, let's modify the notation slightly to make it look like it's a frequency response for a discrete-time system:

$$  \begin{align}
H \left( e^{j \omega} \right) & = \csc(\omega) \\
& = \frac{1}{\sin(\omega)} \\
& = \frac{2j}{e^{j \omega} - e^{-j \omega}} \\
& = \frac{2j \ e^{-j \omega}}{1 - (e^{-j \omega})^2} \\
\end{align}$$

so i guess that means that
$$H(z) = \frac{2j \ z^{-1}}{1 - z^{-2}}$$

so can you get a difference equation from that?

Comment: Thank you that clears it up.  I can't believe that never crossed my mind.

Answer (score 0):

replace h(z) by the output by input form y(z)/x(z).now cross multiply by the numerator and denominator of the transfer function. now if suppose x(z)*pow(z,-1) appears in the time domain write it as x(n-1). finally bring it into y(n)=(combination of x(n) terms and y(n) terms)..

regards,
phani tej